# ALT + insert not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

ALT + insert is not working in my Android Studio. It is AS 3.0. 
I remember I have used it in previous versions. Also it works properly in IntelliJ.
Could anybody help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `File->Settings->Keymap` and check your settings for `Generate`:

[image]

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it seems everything is good there, shortcut is set properly.

Comment: @natansalda you can try by, right click on the code area and then choose generate.

Comment: thanks :) the problem is I am using an extension forcing me to use keyboeard shortcuts, so to generate anything autoatically I will need to disable it, as me shortcut in this example doesn't work/ But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

if you try all methods and still not working!!
it could be a plugin responsible for this issuse, So:

###### Disable All Plugins and restart Android Studio...

If working fine then the issue is with one or more plugin

for me, it was "**Flutter Enhancement Suit**"
Working fine after disabling it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>. This worked for me.